# I can't get setInterval to work for me

Tags: javascript

I have a function called start that is triggered when you push the start button. The start function calls another function called getRandomImage. I want getRandomImage to repeat every 5 seconds, but I just can't get the setInterval method to work for me. I've tried putting the interval on the start function, but that just causes it to fire off once, and doesn't repeat. I've tried putting the interval on the getRandomImages function, but then it doesn't do anything. Essentially I am trying to make a color blindness test that flashes a random image every 5 seconds until 30 images have passed or the user clicks a button. I've been banging my head against this for over 8 hours, and am really questioning my choice in programming languages right now, lol.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ColorPerceptionTest.css">


</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <img src="Default.png" id="defaultimage">

        <form>
            <input type="button" id="Button1" value="" onClick="">
            <input type="button" id="Button2" value="" onClick="">
            <input type="button" id="Button3" value="" onClick="">
            <br>
            <input type="button" id="Start" value="Start" onClick="start()">
            <input type="button" id="Help" value="Help" onClick="help()">
            <br>
            <p id="help"> </p>

        </form>

    </section>


    <script>
        var $ = function(id) {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }

        $("Button1").style.display = "none";
        $("Button2").style.display = "none";
        $("Button3").style.display = "none";


        var imagesArray = ["3.gif", "05.gif", "5.gif", "6.gif", "7.gif",
                           "8.gif", "12.gif", "15.gif", "16.gif", "26.gif",
                           "29.gif", "42.gif", "45.gif", "73.gif",
                           "74.gif"];

        var runTimer = setInterval(start, 5000);

        function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {
            path = path || 'images/';  
            var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
            var img = imgAr[ num ];
            var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
            $("defaultimage").src = path + img;

            $("Button1").style.display = "initial";
            $("Button2").style.display = "initial";
            $("Button3").style.display = "initial";

            if(parseInt(img) < 8){
                $("Button1").value = parseInt(img);
                $("Button2").value = parseInt(img) - 2;
                $("Button3").value = parseInt(img) + 1;
            }else if(parseInt(img) > 7 && parseInt(img) < 29){
                $("Button1").value = parseInt(img) - 2;
                $("Button2").value = parseInt(img);
                $("Button3").value = parseInt(img) + 1;
            }else{
                $("Button1").value = parseInt(img) - 5;
                $("Button2").value = parseInt(img) - 9;
                $("Button3").value = parseInt(img);
            }
        }


        var start = function(){
            $("help").innerHTML = "";
            getRandomImage(imagesArray);
            $("Start").style.display = "none";
            $("Help").style.display = "none";


        }

        var help = function (){
            $("help").innerHTML = "This is a test designed to help you determine" +
                    " if you have a problem with seeing colors. When you press start, a series of " +
                    "random images will be displayed. You have 5 seconds to read the number and " + 
                    "select the correct button.";
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: `$("Button1")` is looking for a tag named Button1, unlikely to be what you want. Have you added logging to start? I'm pretty sure it is getting caked more than once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the `setInterval` call to a point where `start` is defined...

Your code works fine in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pp7cke7a/).

```
var start = function(){
    $("help").innerHTML = "";
    getRandomImage(imagesArray);
    $("Start").style.display = "none";
    $("Help").style.display = "none";
}
var runTimer = setInterval(start, 5000);
```

Update: To make it more clear, had OP written `function start()` the posted code would have been properly hoisted. But, as he used a function expression, `start` is undefined when `setInterval` is called.

Another update: Here's [a forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pp7cke7a/1/) to correct the timer based on the button and the comments below.

Comment: A function definition is always hoisted to the top of its container function. Your suggestion cannot possibly change anything

Comment: Yet my fiddle works and his doesn't? Additional relevant console output from jsfiddle: `ReferenceError: start is not defined`

Comment: Oops, my bad, I didn't realize the function was being assigned to a variable. That's true, start will be undefined when setInterval is called.. another thing that would work would be to change the function to be `function start(){...}`

Comment: Thank you. This is almost perfect, however it is starting the image rotation before the start button is clicked, which I want to avoid. I tried changing it to "var runTimer = setInterval(getRandomImage, 5000);"  but then it threw "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined", so I tried "var runTimer = setInterval(getRandomImage(imagesArray), 5000);" but then it does nothing.

Comment: Yes, as soon as you `setInterval` the clock starts. So don't set the interval until the button is pressed.

Comment: @UKXK189 I've added another fiddle to show you what I mean. Hope that solves your problems.

Comment: Thanks, I was just about to say I got it. Thanks for your help Tony.